# Listen all buttons events Android

Tags: android, button, listener

Its possible to have a listener to all buttons without setting the onClickListener in each button across all activities? and without making a extends button with the listener already set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Each view has to be told what to listen to.  You can specify it in xml if you prefer with the onClick attribute, but you'll still need to specify it on each object.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, I was suspecting that.

Answer (score 0):

If all the buttons are doing the exact same thing, you can include that in the List kind of a layout and have one button with just one onCLick() event

Comment: my gold where is to make no changes in the activities

Comment: I would need to know what you are trying to accomplish before i could add anything here

Comment: lets assume that i want to send an event to an analytics platform, when I click any button, and I want to change as less as possible in the existent conde